# unknown attribute 'email' for [has_many association] when trying to create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, associations

I have a model `User` that i've set up a `has_many`/`belongs_to` association with `posts`, and I'm trying to test my posts controller in rspec. However, when I try to create a post that belongs to a user, I get the error:  `undefined method 'email=' for #<Post:0x00000...>`

I am creating the Post like so:

```
before(:each) do
        @user = User.create!({email: "email@gmail.com", password: "password"})
        @post = @user.posts.create!({title: "title", content: "content"})
end
```

I'm not sure why it's trying to find an `email` method for the post, as there is none that exists. 
I also get this error when I try to create a new post in the rails console. I can do `p = Post.new(...)`, but i get the error when I save it. (`p.save!`)

I also get the error when I try to create a post like so:

`Post.create({title: "title", content: "content", user_id: 1 })`

Does anyone have any idea why this error is showing up and how I can fix it? Thanks!

--

My post model looks like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: What does your `Post` model look like?

Comment: @iceman I added this in to the question.

Comment: Ok, devise by default requires an email column.

Comment: Also, devise is usually in your `User` model as opposed to the `Post` model.

Comment: Wow that was it, thanks. I had put the devise line in there because I thought it might be required as a result of the association. If you want to add it as an answer I'll mark yours correct. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it worked, I made an answer to wrap it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in the `Post` model is causing the problems. `devise` by default requires an email column so that is why it's complaining of it not existing. Simply remove the line from the `Post` model.

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the given information, this is how the files should look:

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :posts
end
```

**models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**User migration**

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :email, null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
      t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      t.string :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string :unconfirmed_email

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :name
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token, unique: true
    add_index :users, :unlock_token, unique: true
  end
end
```

**Post migration**

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :notes do |t|
      t.string :title, null: false
      t.text :content, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```